# Magento2: How to implement ENUM datatype?

Tags: magento2, custom-options

Working on custom extension and need to implement ENUM datatype.

In Magento1, we use to implement in this way,

```
$installer->run("
ALTER TABLE `{$this->getTable('catalog_product_option_type_price')}` CHANGE `price_type` `price_type` ENUM( 'fixed', 'percent', 'absolute' ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'fixed' 
");
```

How to make this work for Magento2?

Comment: You can do same way in M2.

Answer (score 4):

It's (ENUM datatype) not supported in Magento 2

You can get more info from @ Igor Minyaylo [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95434/magento-2-create-table-field-with-enum-data-type)